# Ошибка аватара в Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код ошибки: 0x80070422
В интернете пишут про центр обновлений, но проблема же не с ним. Установил все обновления за январь 2024 но ошибка так и осталась. Частично решил заменив стандартные эскизы на своё изображение. Так вот, подкажите, как можно исправить эту ошибку? Или хотя бы подскажите где хранятся стандартные эскизы с экрана блокировки. **Кстати, это локальная учётная запись, я знаю что можно добавить Microsoft и там сменить но это не вариант**